RUM agent ignore URL parts before send data to Elastic APM server
How can I avoid the problem of excessive transactions by ignoring parts of the URL before sending it to the APM server?
Example: my application has a route similar to this:
/levels/:foo/:bar
Where foo and bar are random numbers.
Is there a way to send only '/levels' to the APM server?
